# Testing javascript code with npm without serving a webpage

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

For part of a testing suite, I'd like to be able to run some Javascript (not serve it and visit it using a web browser), and have the Javascript either dump some status information to console output or a file. Is this possible?

Comment: What is this information and where it's supposed to originate from? For testing, Jest with Puppeteer or JSDOM may be of some use

Answer (score 0):

Yes. But you need to give a bit more context.
Since you are tagging this with node.js, this is as simple as:

myNodeScript.js

```
//Anywhere that is being executed...
console.log("Some message");

//or
const fs = require('fs');
fs.writeFile('filename', 'some data', err => console.log(err || 'OK'));
```

But obviously you would have figured this out by now, so I am guessing there is more to the question. E.g. your mentioning you want to do this as part of a testing suite.

What kind of testing suite, are you talking abstract or are you using a specific tool? Is that tool browser driven or nodejs driven etc.

Just in general, what do you have now and what have you tried?